# Pandas does not have a function "read_sql"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.6

Python 3.6 on RHEL 8, Pandas 1.1.5

Trying to use pandas to do a query, `pd.read_sql(<my query>, conn).to_dict(orient="records")`

Error message is: `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_sql'`

At the command line, `python3 -c "import pandas; print(str(pandas.__dict__))"` returns, among other things, `'read_sql': <function read_sql at 0x7eff9c08df28>` so the function is obviously there and visible to Python. It is using the version of Pandas from the venv in the Pandas distro from pip not some other random local file called pandas or pd.

Please advise, why is this happening?

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling, no good.

Update with new information: This does not occur in the Python test server, but does only with WSGI.

My Python Path in WSGI (getting the error):

```
"['/var/www/FLASKAPPS/',
'/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp',
'/usr/lib64/python36.zip', 
'/usr/lib64/python3.6',
'/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
'/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', 
'/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']"
```

This is the WSGI `pandas.__dict__`:

```
"{'__name__': 'pandas', '__doc__': None, '__package__': 'pandas', '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external._NamespaceLoader object at 0x7f56025be668>, '__spec__': ModuleSpec(name='pandas', loader=None, origin='namespace', submodule_search_locations=_NamespacePath(['/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas', '/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas'])), '__path__': _NamespacePath(['/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas', '/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas'])}"
```

My Python Path in the Python test server (no error):

```
"['/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp',
'/usr/lib64/python36.zip',
'/usr/lib64/python3.6',
'/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload',
'/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages',
'/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']"
```

And here is a partial of the `pandas.__dict__` from the working Python test server:

```
origin='/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py', submodule_search_locations=['/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas']), '__path__': ['/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas'], '__file__': '/var/www/FLASKAPPS/myapp/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py'
```

### "Solution"

Not really a solution, but at least I finally found the cause of the issue. Apparently, pandas uses numpy, which is not compatible with mod_wsgi, when running on RHEL 8. Python, in its infinite wisdom, would not include this in the error output.

Thanks to everyone that looked at this for me, sorry the answer is not so fulfilling.

Comment: Does `pd.io.sql.read_sql` work?

Comment: It gives the same error message: `return pd.io.sql.read_sql("SHOW DATABASES;", self.get_connection()).to_dict(orient="records") -> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_sql'
`

Comment: The error you are getting must be from another line/file. This line's error would be: `module 'pandas.io.sql' has no attribute 'read_sql`

Comment: That is what I would have expected as well. But those are the last two lines of the error output. I am starting to suspect that the issue has something to do with the venv path. If I run it from the command line it works, WSGI it doesn't, but it is the same python path as far as I can tell...

Comment: Do you have a file names `pandas.py` or a directory `pandas`? That may confuse python (looking to the wrong place)

Comment: Not that I have been able to find. Trying to figure out a way to find the path to where Python thinks pandas.py is, but not sure how to do that. printing pandas.__dict__ is only outputting the search path in the nonworking WSGI app.

Comment: I added the python paths to the question in hopes that may help.

Comment: To avoid anymore context questions, please provide a full code block and not a single line snippet so we can see fuller context including all relevant `import` lines and object assignments. BTW - Pandas 1.1.5 is a bit dated as current version is 1.5.3.